# plotting graph using class list in python

Tags: python, list, matplotlib, graph, vehicle-routing

I am trying to plot my data into a path graph. I trying to create a random path for 4 cars and this 4 wants to visit 5 customers.

```
    #supplier_number = car _number
    customer_number=5
    supplier_number=4
    def new_xy_point():
        # data to be resides in 1st quadrant 0,90
        return uniform(0,90), uniform(0, 90)
def get_locations_as_xy(customer_number,supplier_number):
    array_xy = []
    for i in range(supplier_number):
        row =[]
        points = (new_xy_point() for x in range(customer_number)) 
        for point in points:
            row.append(point)
        array_xy.append(row)
    return array_xy
```

the output is:

```
[[(79.8124249272261, 44.151314843376966),
  (49.58192180840642, 30.506482732663542),
  (70.28912677528703, 6.087441061797694),
  (89.72384322616452, 9.047722517152833),
  (27.28544284379016, 80.71213796853516)],
 [(66.13756351247677, 23.709450654837315),
  (35.80512730273459, 0.6473958875768127),
  (4.12310992239377, 8.115202500984706),
  (9.07346347106888, 5.2704030998187665),
  (33.055743597036425, 46.21644665009771)],
 [(78.3715863238612, 25.13391992214651),
  (35.348720737093714, 46.79846937389697),
  (0.38478865512179605, 10.88617671535756),
  (80.24554838153814, 50.51948471537834),
  (60.38633980419526, 30.12729562579119)],
 [(70.16475539031165, 67.44148335547648),
  (26.47817748165972, 2.181339809429085),
  (24.303755071847856, 27.091607591419606),
  (35.889393671532545, 11.733938313695619),
  (26.76256015621871, 55.21515150952254)]]
```

here I have x-axis and y-axis for each customer. I need to plot a graph based on these values.I need output something like this [i.stack.imgur.com/FH7bE.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FH7bE.png)
I am inexperienced with python and plotting g, so any advice is appreciated.

Comment: Question has actually nothing to do with `machine-learning` - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Comment: Can you clarify your problem? The title says "plotting graph using class list in python" but I don't see a class list in this code. Is your issue with plotting (What have you tried? What error did you encounter?) or with handling the data (What problem needs solving? Did you encounter any errors?). Please see the [ask] page how to best help us help you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use matplotlib to plot data easily.

First convert your data to a x and y list.
Here I call your list of datapoints a.
One path per vehicle, marked by a respective number.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

for idx, row in enumerate(a):
    x, y = [], []
    for x_, y_ in row:
        x.append(x_)
        y.append(y_)
     plt.plot(x, y, label=idx)

plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

In the data you provided, you have a lot of duplicates, resulting in 5 points in total.

Comment: sorry that was a mistake while copy from IDE. Now I modified it

Comment: not exactly. I need to get a separate path for 4  cars in a single graph

Comment: Edited answer with one plot per vehicle.

Comment: yes. after using covert my all x and y-axis in the same array. I need  something like this 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/FH7bE.png

Comment: And that is what you get with the code?  https://i.ibb.co/tbGcyqh/img.png